# Ubuntu equivalents to MacOS shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

I went from Macos to Ubuntu. And it not easy as always. Problem with buttons.
There everything not like in home. Task switch isnt comant+tab

- app exit is not command+q
- copy is not command+c
- paste is not command+v
- select all text not is command+A

Help me please to do every thing to fill my self in Ubuntu like in home, mean Macos. If you will advice me some soft, please show Icon too, because to many different soft in repos, need to see Icon.
And please give me as much advices as you can, I will thankful. Honestly.

Thank you Guyz!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no "command" button on non-mac keyboards. So you can't use a key that doesn't exist ;)

However, the good news is that almost all of these shortcuts are essentially the same, you just need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>. So:

- app exit is Ctrl+Shift+q (OK, this one is a little different)
- copy is Ctrl+c
- paste is Ctrl+v
- select all text is Ctrl+A

It is also trivial to change these. Click on the settings icon on the top right, then System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows. There you can assign whatever you like.